# MS CRM Web Resource is not visible on Android 7.0 device

Tags: android, dynamics-crm, webresource

I have a Web Resource with a button and some functionalities for some Entities in MS Dynamics 365 CRM.
I have checked the checkbox "Enable for tablet" when I imported the solution for it. Also every time when I am using it in some Form I am checking the corresponding "Enable for tablet" checkbox:
[image: Enable for tablets]

Then I configured the section for the all entity forms which includes the Web Resources as "Available on phone". And finally set the "Available on phone" property of the tab where the Web resource is placed:
[image: Available on phone]

As a result: used Web resource is visible in Microsoft Dynamics 365 for tablets and phones
but is not visible on Android phones(tested on version 7.0). Not checked yet on iOS devices.
My question is what could be the reason this Web Resource does not appear on Android devices?